# How to export and import Run/Debug configurations in PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I have a lot of similar projects created in PHPStorm and I need the same Run/Debug configuration in all my projects. Right now the Run/Debug configuration is empty when I create a new project.

I have tried exporting and importing settings from the file menu but that does not copy the Run/Debug configuration of project A into project B.

**Can someone please tell me how to copy the Run/Debug configuration of one project into another?**

Comment: I've created a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32199) for cross-project Run/Debug configurations in PHPstorm.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Run/Debug Configurations are project-specific and therefore **cannot** be exported/imported via `File | Export/Import Settings...` **which is for IDE-wide settings only**.

---

By default, all Run/Debug configurations are stored in `YourProject/.idea/workspace.xml` file together with other *developer-specific settings*.

In order to be able to share (better say -- copy) between the projects:

1. Make sure that each of such Run/Debug configurations has **"Shared" box ticked**.
2. Such shared run configurations will be stored in separate `*.xml` files in `YourProject/.idea/runConfigurations/` folder which you can include in VCS if necessary.
3. You can copy these files from one project to another (while project is closed in IDE, of course).

Comment: awesome! just what i needed.. thanks so much for the fast reply.. also one minor thing, inside the run configuration, i am using absolute paths like `e:\project1\vendor\lib\cli\bin\runit`.. is there a way to use path relative to project directory, e.g. `vendor\lib\cli\bin\runit` where `e:\project1` is my project directory?

Comment: Inside (in .xml file) it is stored relative to the project root anyway (at least this is what I see in 2 *simple* configs I have just tested). If it's not (e.g. path points outside of the project or whatever) -- then no -- path macros are not supported in Run/Debug Configurations